# Update CoreData relationship object in SwiftUI

Tags: core-data, swiftui

I need your help about a SwiftUI/CoreData topic.

I have a `Kid` class containing a one-to-many relationship called `parents` that is a `NSSet?` of `Parent` objects.

I would like to access and be able to update properties of my `parents` relationship objects.
I created a computed property `parentsArray` to get an array from the `NSSet`. Here is the code:

```
public var parentsArray: [Parent] {
    let set = parents as? Set<Parent> ?? []
    return set.sorted {
        $0.position < $1.position
    }
}
```

Now, let's go to my SwiftUI view:

```
ForEach(viewModel.kid.parentsArray) { parent in
    Section(header: Text("Parent \(parent.position)")) {
        TextField("Name", text: $parent.firstName) // Error: Cannot find $parent in scope                   
    }
}
```

As you can see, the problem is that I can't access to the binding `$parent.firstName`.

The `ForEach` loop local variable `parent` is of type `Parent`.

Can you help me ? Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TextField` expects `Binding`, but your calculable `parentsArray` provides CoreData objects.

It is better to separate `TextField` into standalone view with observed `Parent`, like

```
struct ParentView: View {
  @ObservedObject var parent: Parent    // allows binding 

  var body: some View {
     TextField("Name", text: $parent.firstName)
  }
}
```

and then use it in section, like

```
ForEach(viewModel.kid.parentsArray) { parent in
    Section(header: Text("Parent \(parent.position)")) {
        ParentView(parent: parent) 
    }
}
```

Comment: It works fine this way, thank you so much ! Actually, I have 5 TextFields so I'll have to create a new view for each one since it's difficult to reuse it. But I don't think I have other choice. Thanks again !